# Change assembly version in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm making unit test for code which gets calling frame of callstack and gets version of calling assembly.

```
var method = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
var version = method.ReflectedType.Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

For testing purposes i'd like to not depend on current testing assembly version and change it programmatically.

Is there any way to change it in runtime? Or it is forbidden by CLR for security purposes?

Comment: Take back ten steps and consider whether basing your logic on the version of the calling assembly is actually what you want to do.

Comment: No, its ok, that this code gets version of testing assembly, but i'd like to set this version for this test programmatically

Comment: Check out this link. I'm not sure it gives you exactly what you want, but maybe it does. It's not changing it, but you can built whatever version you want.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyw13ks6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It doesnt work, because the method Assembly.GetName() returns new AssemblyName(); So - i cant set version this way

Comment: Create a `Mock` of Assembly that returns default values for everything but the ones you change?